# Call function by name and pass hashtable parameter in C#

Tags: c#, invoke

I have a function that calls other functions dynamically via name. I need to pass a hashtable to the function being called. I have the code working in VB.Net but while trying to convert it to C# I am running into a error when I try to pass the hashtable as a parameter. Can someone explain what is happening and how I can resolve it?

This is the working VB.Net code:

```
Dim objTF As New ThreadFunctions 
Dim objResults As Object = CallByName(objTF, htParameters.Item("strMethodName"), CallType.Get, htParameters)
```

Here is the C# code:

```
ThreadFunctions objTF = new ThreadFunctions();
Type objType = objTF.GetType();
MethodInfo miMethod = objType.GetMethod(htParameters["strMethodName"].ToString());
object objResults = miMethod.Invoke(objTF, htParameters); //This line has the issue
```

*Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])' has some invalid arguments*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
object objResults = miMethod.Invoke(objTF, (object)htParameters);
```

As the `params` second argument threats the hashtable wrong.

Comment: I made the change and the error is still the *Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])' has some invalid arguments*

Comment: Almost there: object objResults = miMethod.Invoke(objTF, new object[] { htParameters });